# Labels created with jquery not responding

Tags: jquery, tags, append

when I create an html tag, for example:

```
 $j('#edit-gen').append("<a class=reloadInput href=javascript:void(0)> change </a>");


$j('.reloadInput').click(function(){
alert("test");

});
```

and I want to use, such as with an click event, not answer,but if the label already created if it responds.It as if there were.
Thanks in advance, sorry for my English

Comment: Seems to work just fine -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PWs2c/), did you remember document ready etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use some delegation as with `.on()`:

```
$j(document).on('click','.reloadInput',function(){
    alert("test");    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure but I think quotes would be needed to wrap the class "reloadInput" and "javascript:void(0)"